# How to pass data from Activity to fragment inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an `Activity`. It adds `Fragment A` dynamically. `Fragment A` contains static added (by xml) child `Fragment B`. How can I pass data from `Activity` to `Fragment B` when i add `Fragment A` to `Activity`?


I know next approach:
Implement interface getter in `Activity` and call getter method from `Fragment B`

I'd like to know, are there another ways to do it?

I tried set arguments from `Activity` to `Fragment A`, find `Fragment B` by child fragment manager and set arguments from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`.
But `Fragment B` created earlier than `Fragment A`, so i had exceptions..

Answer (score 2):

Well there are more than one ways to accomplish that. one of the way is
Create a function public void setData(Data data) in your Fragment B

Transfer your data from Activity to Fragment A. Since your Fragment B is added by fragment tag in xml. create ref to your Fragment B object in Fragment A. Now you have the reference to Fragment B in A.

Now Simply call the function (created in Fragment B) in Fragment A and pass the data which you have received by the Activity

Other way..

In Fragment B you can call getActivity() and type cast it in to your Activity class type and call its method which can return the desired data

Comment: thank's i 've implemented fist way by myself already.  i got Fragment B reference in  onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) method of Fragment B

Answer (score 0):

This sample by google should resolve all your Issues:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Such way i've discribed above

Answer (score 0):

You can try [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to pass data from Activity to your Fragment B. In your activity call this `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());`

And then you just need to register EventBus in onCreateView of Fragment B

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And then

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){

    // DO SOMETHING
}
```